# Specific glob pattern not matching after broad exclude

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob, gulp

I am using Gulp as a build process and I have recently run into some problems with page-specific files injection (through gulp-inject fyi).

Some context: I am grabbing all the HTML files, and then go over them one at a time so I can use their filename to include specific files into the glob collection, for example for `index.html` I have:

```
[
    'export/assets/js/libs/jquery*.js',    // jQuery first
    'export/assets/js/libs/*.js',          // Followed by all the libs
    'export/assets/js/*.js',               // Followed by any other js file
    '!export/assets/js/view-*.js',         // Excluding all view-* files [see note]
    '!export/assets/**/_*.js',             // Excluding underscore prefixed files
    '!export/assets/js/ie*.js',            // Excluding all IE libs
    'export/assets/js/view-index*.js'      // Including page specific file
]
```

*[note] There might be more page-specific files, eg. `view-profile.js` or `view-contact.js` but in this iteration, only `view-index.js` can be included.*

The above collection is then `gulp.src()`'d and processed, only, `view-index.js` never makes it into the stream..

**EDIT:**

I accepted the answer below because it pointed out that what I had wasn't going to suffice in achieving my goal. I found a work-around where I pass in `export/assets/js/**/*.js` and filter out what I don't need through [gulp-ignore](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-ignore/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since minimatch doesn't explicitly support negate globbing patterns, most libraries implement something like "collect all the negations, now call minimatch on the rest, now apply all the negations."  See https://github.com/wearefractal/glob-stream/blob/master/index.js#L28  (Note [glob-stream](https://github.com/wearefractal/glob-stream) is used by [vinyl-fs](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs) which is exposed as [gulp's src](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/index.js#L25).)

Comment: So you are saying that I won't be able to get the above working through gulp's default `src()`? The weird thing is that it worked when I implemented it, but I haven't needed this feature up until now, which is when I noticed that it wasn't working anymore.

Comment: Accepted this as an answer as there is no obvious solution to this. I updated my original question with my workaround fix.